# How to use google map in ios instead of default map?

Tags: ios, google-maps, ios6, mkmapview

I want google map in my native app instead of default mapkit map in ios 6.

Comment: Yes now u ca go for it https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will want to use the Google Maps SDK: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/

Comment: It's easy to work with, it does a few thing less than the current iOS 6 Apple Mapkit, but it otherwise quite similar to use.